# I want to draw multiple rectangle using loops in android

Tags: android

I want to take user input in numbers and based on that input I want to draw multiple numbers of rectangles on screen using for loop.

This is the image that I want to implement.
[image]
thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the user trying to create a table ? You can do this in two ways. Either by using RecyclerView or by using a CustomView (with custom drawing) I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Probably the simplest way is to draw rects to a canvas using 2 nested for loops, like so:

```
        for (int n = 0; n < numRows; n++){
            for (int m = 0; m < numColumns; m++){
            
             canvas.drawRect(leftMargin + m*columnWidth, topMargin + n*rowHeight,
             leftMargin + m*columnWidth + width, topMargin + n*rowHeight + height, myPaint);
                    
            }
        }
```

where:

`numRows` = # of rows to draw
`numColumns` = # of columns to draw
`leftmargin` = distance from left side of screen to first column
`topMargin` = distance from top of screen to first row
`columnWidth` = width of each column of rects
`rowHeight` = heigth of each row of rects
`width` = width of each rect, if equal to columnWidth there will be no space between rects.
`height` = height of each rect, if equal to rowHeight there will be no space between.
`myPaint` = the Paint object you define for your rects, where you would specify things like color, filled in or outline, opacity, etc.